# Could someone explain queue() and dequeue() in this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I generally understand how `queue()` and `dequeue()` work, but this function looks really encrypted to me:

```
function displayMessage (msg) {
                $('#info').queue(function() {
                  $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0).queue(function() {
                    $(this).text(msg).dequeue()
                  }).fadeTo('slow', 1).dequeue(); 
                })
}
```

What is really going on here?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/queue/ http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/

Comment: .dequeue simply tells the queue when to continue. this is the old way of doing it, the new way is to accept a parameter to the .queue callback named `next`, then executing that parameter (it's a function) when you want the queue to continue. The old way should still work though.

Comment: the queue show or manipulates the msgs to be executed and dequeue executes the next function of queue, in this case next message if any.

Comment: But why fadeTo('slow', 1) is constantly executed? Isn't supposed to be called just first time?

Comment: it will be called once for every time displayMessage is executed.

Comment: I have just one more question.Why is dequeue() necessary here $(this).text(msg).dequeue() ?  Did $(this).text(msg) add something to the queue or ?

Comment: No, you have two things you're adding to the queue. The .dequeue after .text() continues the queue after the first .fadeTo, the second .dequeue continues the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.dequeue` simply tells the queue when to continue. this is the old way of doing it, the new way is to accept a parameter to the `.queue` callback named `next`, then executing that parameter (it's a function) when you want the queue to continue. The old way should still work though. Ref: http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Your code could be simplified to this:

```
function displayMessage(msg) {
    $('#info').fadeTo('slow', 0, function(){
        $(this).text(msg).fadeTo('slow',1);
    });
}
```

However i find displaying a message like this to be annoying. I'd suggest speeding up the animation, or possibly removing the animation and instead doing a highlight effect to bring attention to the message.

Note, this will still take into account existing messages that are still fading in and out.

Comment: +1 I wasn't aware of the old way (do you remember until which version it was in use?). Wow I'm too new with jQuery...

Comment: The new way was added in 1.4, the old way is still valid, it just isn't as easy to read in code.